# How to center text between 2 points php?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to center some text between to points. The text is dynamic and should be centered no matter what it contains.

I am trying the following:

```
    $dims = imagettfbbox(130, 0, './Calibri.ttf', "JULY");

$width = ($dims[2])-($dims[0]);

imagettftext($my_img , 130, 0, 1196-($width/2) , 700, $text_colour, './Calibri.ttf', "JULY");
```

I have a point at x = 711 and a point at x = 1907 and this is where I get the 1196 from because 1907-711 = 1196.

In my logic the `1196-($width/2)` should work as the parameter is the first pixel of the text.

But as it can be seen on the image, it is not centered.
[image: My test]

Comment: This is not suitable to be an answer, but you should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#68518 which has the solution for you.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a PHP solution. There are other simple solutions such as css etc.

Comment: you don't take into consideration the width of the string, i agree with humble, use simple CSS solution if possible

Comment: @TheHumbleRat The code is used to create an image. I don't believe you can use CSS.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I tried using your suggested solution '$dims = imagettfbbox(130, 0, './Calibri.ttf', "JULY");

$width = abs($dims[4])-($dims[0]);

imagettftext($my_img , 130 , 0, 1196-($width/2), 700, $text_colour, './Calibri.ttf', "JULY");'   But it gave the same result.

Comment: @RamHS I think that the `abs()` is used as  `abs($dims[4]-$dims[0]);` instead of `abs($dims[4])-($dims[0]);`. But check the answer that mudasobwa posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your explanation I understood that `1196-($width/2)` is wrong.

You should find the middle of the box, laying between `x = 711` and `x = 1907`:

```
$x_center = 711 + (1907 - 711) / 2 
$x_start = $x_center - ($width / 2)
```

Hope it helps.